# Qu'est-ce que ça veux dire « pécho » ?

Tags: expressions, argot, verlan

Qu'est-ce que veux dire: « Il a pécho tape dans tes mains » ?? 
J'ai toujours entendu ce mot « pécho » mais je ne le comprends pas !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

“Pécho” veut dire “choper”, c'est-à-dire, familièrement, [“prendre” ou “attraper”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choper). Souvent, ça peut aussi vouloir dire “voler quelquechose” ou encore “séduire” (*pick up* in English). “Il a pécho tape dans tes mains” pourrait être un commentaire facétieux de quelqu'un qui apprend qu'une autre personne a trouvé un partenaire potentiel (je formule ça de la façon la plus neutre possible mais enfin j'imagine plus un jeune homme le dire à propos d'un autre homme qui a rencontré une femme que dans une autre situation).

Comment: Oui, il était référé à une photo où un mec avait sa main sur l'épouse de sa femme. Donc ça veux dire quelque chose comme "tu as trouvé l'amour"? Mais pourquoi "tape"? Et pourquoi "tes mains"?

Comment: @Chiara “Tape dans tes mains” = “applaudis”. Il y a différentes variantes du genre “si tu blablabla tape dans tes mains”, apparemment tirées d'une comptine. Potentiellement sous-entendu: c'était dur pour lui, il faut l'encourager.

Comment: Ooohh okk!! Merci beaucoup! :D

Comment: Bien entendu si l'autre personne est présente, c'est une blague un peu lourde et une situation plutôt embarassante.

Answer (score 6):

Pécho c'est du verlan, une vieille forme de communication où on inverse les syllabes. C'est donc "choper", l'argot pour dire attraper et aujourd'hui on l'emploie le plus souvent pour dire qu'on a séduit quelqu'un. Coucher avec quelqu'un pour être plus précis.

Comment: C'est juste. Notons aussi : la langue de la rue étant ce qu'elle est (rapidement changeante), le terme a servi a désigner pas mal d'autres choses. Comme le fait d'acheter différentes drogues illégales, notamment.

Comment: Je ne savais pas que verlan est une vieille forme. Je toujours pensait que c'est assez nouveau.